# How to submit a new value to a field where its rendering is controlled by a boolean property in JSF?

Tags: jsf

I have a h:panelGroup which displays a output date based on the value of a boolean property. When the form the submitted with a new date value to `budgetEffectiveDateText`, the new value is coming in as `null` to the controller. When the `rendered="#{orderController.reviseMode}"` property is removed from the panelGroup, or when I use `rendered="true"`, I get the new given date for the field. How can I pass the new value for the field with the rendered property set by the bean's boolean property?

```
<h:panelGroup id="budgetPanel" rendered="#{orderController.reviseMode}">
    <tr>
        <td class="required_field_medium" >
            <h:outputText value="Budget Effective Date"></h:outputText>
        </td>
        <td>
            <h:inputText id="budgetEffectiveDateText" value="#{orderController.order.ioBudget.budgetEffectiveDate}"
                         converter="DateTimeConverter"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `rendered` attribute is re-evaluated during form submit as well as part of safeguard against tampered requests. So if the bean is request scoped and the `reviseMode` boolean is initialized based on some request scoped value which is absent during form submit, then it will default to `false` and then JSF won't process the inputs contained in the panel group.

It's unclear which JSF version you're using (please mention it in future questions), but if it's JSF 2.x, then the solution is easy: put the bean in the view scope instead of the request scope.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class OrderController {
    // ...
}
```

If you're still on JSF 1.x, then there are several ways depending on how exactly you're initializing the `reviseMode` condition. One of the best ways is to just simulate the JSF 2.x view scope using Tomahawk's `<t:saveState>` tag or RichFaces' `<a4j:keepAlive>` tag.

Comment: Thanks BalusC! I am using JSF 2.x. The value of the `reviseMode` seems to be set properly and I am able to view the contents of the panel. But when the reviseMode is true and I give in a new date value to the field, I get it as null on submitting the form.

Comment: Yes, I answered that you've to put the bean in the view scope instead of the request scope. Did it solve your problem?